# How do you add an extra query string parameter via a form submit in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to be able to add an additional query string parameter on submit that is the same as the value of the `classrooms_search_textbox` that the user will type.  How do I do this?

```
<%= form_tag classrooms_path, :method => :get, :id => "classrooms_search_form" do %>
<%= text_field_tag "classrooms_search_textbox", "Find a classroom" %>
<%= submit_tag "Find", :id => "classrooms_search_button", :class => "button" %>
```

Do I need to add a `hidden_tag` (and if so, how would I go about doing this?) or can I just add to the `classrooms_path` somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: What would you like to do with it?

Comment: Hard to describe but its because where I am sending it expects a param named `classrooms_query`.  But I want to retain the `classrooms_search_textbox` for another reason

Comment: By `where you are sending it` you mean a controller, or an external resource?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're sending it your controller first, then you can just manipulate the params in your controller method before sending it off:

```
params[:classrooms_query] = params[:classrooms_search_textbox]
```

And then go ahead and use those params to send off to the other service. There's no need to add hidden field tags or use some fancy JS code.

Comment: I tried doing this.  the `params[:classrooms_query]` does not show up in the following page after the controller action.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_tag classrooms_path, :method => :get, :id => "classrooms_search_form" do %>
  <%= text_field_tag "classrooms_search_textbox", "Find a classroom" %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "classrooms_query" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Find", :id => "classrooms_search_button", :class => "button" %>


$('#classrooms_search_form').submit(function() {
   $('#classrooms_query').value($(classrooms_search_textbox.value());
});
```

That would achieve what you want. Nonetheless, maybe it is in your interest to refactor the controller or view so that it doesn't have this kind of conflicts.